# Why is CrashDump.exe hanging? How to go about debugging?

Tags: gdb, crash-dumps, gdbserver

I'm using the CrashCatcher/CrashDebug code from https://github.com/adamgreen/CrashDebug.
My platform is an STM32H753 running freertos. I've been able to generate a dump file based on the HexDump.c example in CrashCatcher. So far so good. The problem arises when I try to run arm-none-eabi-gdb.exe and connect it to CrashDebug.exe. I'm running on windows 10 and using the stm32 tool chain. I built CrashDebug.exe locally using mingw.  I run the following command line:

```
C:\ST\STM32CubeIDE_1.6.1\STM32CubeIDE\plugins\com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.9-2020-q2-update.win32_2.0.0.202105311346\tools\bin\arm-none-eabi-gdb.exe "fw-10143-sensor-hub-stm32-firmware\Debug\THOR_1.5_Sensor_Hub_FW.elf" -ex "set target-charset ASCII" -ex "target remote | /Users/felix/source/Thor/CrashDebug.exe --elf C:\Users\felix\source\Thor\fw-10143-sensor-hub-stm32-firmware\Debug\THOR_1.5_Sensor_Hub_FW.elf --dump C:\Users\felix\source\Thor\crash.dmp"
```

This runs gdb but the command interpreter becomes unresponsive and never returns to the gdb prompt. I can not even ctrl-c to break. I have to kill the process. Here is what gdb outputs before the hang.

```
C:\ST\STM32CubeIDE_1.6.1\STM32CubeIDE\plugins\com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.9-2020-q2-update.win32_2.0.0.202105311346\tools\bin\arm-none-eabi-gdb.exe: warning: Couldn't determine a path for the index cache directory.
GNU gdb (GNU Tools for STM32 9-2020-q2-update.20201001-1621) 8.3.1.20191211-git
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "--host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=arm-none-eabi".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from fw-10143-sensor-hub-stm32-firmware\Debug\THOR_1.5_Sensor_Hub_FW.elf...
Remote debugging using | /Users/felix/source/Thor/CrashDebug.exe --elf C:\Users\felix\source\Thor\fw-10143-sensor-hub-stm32-firmware\Debug\THOR_1.5_Sensor_Hub_FW.elf --dump C:\Users\felix\source\Thor\crash.dmp
```

I'd expect the gdb prompt to come back so I can get a stack trace out.

I tried running an instance of the mingw gdb and connecting to the running CrashDebug.exe process and halting it. When I do this I get the following stack trace.

```
(gdb) symbol-file c:/users/felix/source/Thor/CrashDebug/bins/win32/CrashDebug.exe
Load new symbol table from "c:\users\felix\source\Thor\CrashDebug\bins\win32\CrashDebug.exe"? (y or n) y
Reading symbols from c:\users\felix\source\Thor\CrashDebug\bins\win32\CrashDebug.exe...done.
(gdb) thread apply all bt

Thread 2 (Thread 3240.0x2804):
#0 0x77154d11 in ntdll!DbgBreakPoint () from C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#1 0x7718dca9 in ntdll!DbgUiRemoteBreakin () from C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#2 0xaa43fb20 in ?? ()
#3 0x7718dc70 in ntdll!DbgUiIssueRemoteBreakin () from C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#4 0x7556fa29 in KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk () from C:\WINDOWS\System32\kernel32.dll
#5 0x77147a7e in ntdll!RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath () from C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#6 0x77147a4e in ntdll!RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath () from C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#7 0x00000000 in ?? ()

Thread 1 (Thread 3240.0xfc4):
#0 0x77152a1c in ntdll!ZwWriteFile () from C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#1 0x7509f32c in WriteFile () from C:\WINDOWS\System32\KernelBase.dll
#2 0x00000134 in ?? ()
#3 0x00000000 in ?? ()
(gdb)
```

Not very helpful. I'm at a loss as to what to do next. Because of the way CrashDebug is launched I can not breakpoint and step through the code to see what is going wrong. Can anyone advise me as to how to get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved (very quickly) by the awesome author.
https://github.com/adamgreen/CrashDebug/issues/18